# Intercept a form submit and prevent or allow submission

Tags: jquery

In my mvc app I have a form that needs to prevent submit from default and resubmit if it’s acceding to my conditions. Even though it give me my alter message form is not resubmiting.

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myform = this;
    var id = $("#itemID").val();
    var brand = $("#brand").val();
    var qty = $('[name=qty]').val();

    $.get("http://192.168.192.106/data/" + id + "?brand=" + brand, function (data, status) {
        var diff = data - qty;
        if ((data - qty) > 0) {
            myform.submit();
        } else {
            alert("Qty is Grater than Stock");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the expected datatype of data?

Answer (score 2):

The first line `e.preventDefault();` stop your submission process. You should use `e.preventDefault();` inside else condition, to make sure submission stop only when validation fail.

Comment: but now form is submitting whether conditions applied or not

Comment: can you try return false; as well

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

**First**
In your code, you have added a `e.preventDefault()` at start that will stop form from being submitted. If all inputs accedes your conditions, you can send these inputs to another page through AJAX.

**Second**
You can add `e.preventDefault()` wherever condition fails.